# I can not build or publish .NET application in Linux

Tags: .net, linux, jenkins, terminal

I want to build and publish the .NET application that I cloned from GitLab with Jenkins.

But when I build and publish with a demo app it stuck at

```
 " Determining projects to restore" show output
```

[image]

and this is `dotnet --info`

[image]

. The app is running fine when I build it in Visual Studio

**I did export PATH env value in the pipeline to solve the Dotnet not found ( this is what I came up with)

folder structure

[image]

Comment: Let's show your solution structure (files, folders/directories). You must run `dotnet publish...` in where has `*.csproj` , not `*.sln` .

Comment: @DoNhuVy the Same happens when i choose .csproj.

Comment: Can you post more information? Error, directory structures, screenshot shows problems, etc. You should remove .NET SDK 3, keep only latest .NET 5 SDK.

Comment: @DoNhuVy i Added a photo,, is having both sdk 3 & 5  a problem?

Comment: What is your Jenkins version? You should remove .NET SDK 3 for avoid any confusing or more complex situation for resolving problem.

Comment: Let's post all of your Jenkins jobs, configuration file. I don't see any error information. Check follow check-list https://faun.pub/jenkins-ci-cd-to-deploy-an-asp-net-core-application-6145b5308bff

Comment: @DoNhuVy The problem is the same when i run in in the terminal, the problem is not jenkins i guess

Comment: @DoNhuVy building and publishing need internet access to reach NuGet packages? 
I'm using a firewall, could it be the reason?

Comment: You see in `obj` and `bin` directory/folder, if size of these folder is big, it means dependencies have been got to your machine. You can create a very minimal project, then try build, publish it, before try build/publish real-world projects. It helps you diagnostic problem more easier.

Comment: @DoNhuVy yes they're big, `obj`  is 40.7MB and `bin` is 38MB.. i don't understand you

Answer (score 0):

The problem was is the packages.
It was missing the packages because they're not pushed to git due the .gitignore file .